# How many Digits in $3^{2020}$

Tags: number-theory, binomial-distribution

[image]

I know n+1 = number of digits in $3^{2020}$

but how to find number of digits .

How can we solve it **without using a calculator** .

---

can we not solve it using binomial

$3^{2020}=9^{1010}=(10-1)^{1010}$

after that I am stuck

Comment: What is the relationship between $\log_{10} x$ and the number of digits in $x$?

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 I think characterstcs= number of digits

Answer (score 6):

Let $x=3^{2020}$

$$\lg x = 2020 \lg 3 \approx 2020(0.477)=963.7$$

$$x=10^{963.7}$$

Hence there are $964$ digits.

Comment: In this we need calculator to calculate . Is there any other method in which we do not require calculator .

Comment: As this question came in a high scool exam in which calculator are not allowed . Otherwise your answer is **best** .

Comment: @Koolman You need a log table, not a calculator per se. They used to be standard in schools.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma sorry but it is not allowed in our exam .

Comment: @Koolman the value of log3 is used most often and can be remembered.

Answer (score 2):

$3^{9} =19683 \approx 20000 \implies 9 \log 3 \approx 4 + \log 2$

$2^{10} = 1024 \approx 1000  \implies \log 2 \approx 0.3$

$ \implies \log 3 \approx \dfrac{4.3}{9} \approx 0.477$

$ \implies \log 3^{2020} = 20020 \log 3 \approx  963.54$

So $3^{2020}$ has $964$ digits.

All this can be made precise by using inequalities.